# salesforce.com functions command to create a compute environment throws error

Tags: salesforce-functions

I am planning to do a POC on salesforce.com functions. i registered for SFDC trial org for functions and i am trying to create a compute environment as mentioned below trying to run the command

sf env create compute -o MyScratchOrgAlias -a MyComputeEnv

from Terminal in MS Visualstudio code

Error is thrown that
sf : The term 'sf' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Could you please help me if i am missing any steps?

I am pasting below link from documentation and section of create a compute environment

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide/create-scratch-org.html

Create a Compute Environment

After creating the scratch org, create a Salesforce compute environment that's associated with the scratch org. Your functions deploy to this compute environment.

sf env create compute -o MyScratchOrgAlias -a MyComputeEnv
-o Alias of the org the compute environment is connected to.
-a Alias for the newly created compute environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm install sfdx-cli@latest-rc -g after running this command issue is resolved.